# ScrollView as element of ContraintLayout is not working in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, scrollview

I have ConstraintLayout and it has header and bottom Button.

I will put ScrollView in the middle of header and bottom.

When I search I see that ScrollView should have only one element, I put LinearLayout in ScrollView.

And ScrollView has height as 0dp sine it should be extended between header and button.

However my ScrollView doesn't work.

What is the prolbem?

Please help me!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rule_header"
        android:paddingVertical="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerScrollView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/goBackBtn"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_circle_gray" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="회원가입"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/registerScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingHorizontal="50dp"
            android:paddingVertical="20dp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
                android:paddingVertical="10dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/avatarImage"
                    android:layout_width="70dp"
                    android:layout_height="70dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/avatar_background"
                    android:clipToOutline="true"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                    android:id="@+id/avatarButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:text="사진 선택"
                    android:textSize="18dp">

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="이름"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/nameInput"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/nameInput"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                    android:textSize="20dp"
                    android:theme="@style/EditTheme"
                    tools:text="신혜정" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/default_button"
        android:text="회원가입 완료"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/registerScrollView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I add a bunch of `ImageView`s inside your main `LinearLayout`, so it's like this:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        ...
        <ImageView/>
        <ImageView/>
        <ImageView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I get this (partially scrolled)

[image: A screenshot of the layout with several images in the scrollable area, large enough that it needs to be scrolled to see them all]

What are you adding that needs to be scrolled? How are you adding it? All a `ScrollView` really is is a `FrameLayout` that needs to be sized so it acts as a "window" in your UI (which you've done with the constraints), and then you put something inside it. Usually another layout with height `wrap_content`, and then you add stuff to that layout and its height grows. If the `ScrollView` is smaller than its contents, then it'll scroll.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is your problem?
If I put more elements in the ScrollView, it works.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/rule_header"
    android:paddingVertical="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerScrollView"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/goBackBtn"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_arrow_circle_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="회원가입"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/registerScrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerBtn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="50dp"
        android:paddingVertical="20dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatarImage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/avatar_background"
            android:clipToOutline="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/avatarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="사진 선택"
            android:textSize="18dp">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="50dp"
        android:paddingVertical="20dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatarImage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/avatar_background"
            android:clipToOutline="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/avatarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="사진 선택"
            android:textSize="18dp">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="50dp"
        android:paddingVertical="20dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
        android:paddingVertical="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatarImage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@drawable/avatar_background"
            android:clipToOutline="true"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/avatarButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="사진 선택"
            android:textSize="18dp">

        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingHorizontal="50dp"
        android:paddingVertical="20dp">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingHorizontal="20dp"
            android:paddingVertical="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/avatarImage"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:background="@drawable/avatar_background"
                android:clipToOutline="true"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_user" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                android:id="@+id/avatarButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="사진 선택"
                android:textSize="18dp">

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/nameLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nameLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="이름"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/nameInput"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/nameInput"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:paddingBottom="15dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:theme="@style/EditTheme"
                tools:text="신혜정" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/registerBtn"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/default_button"
    android:text="회원가입 완료"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/registerScrollView" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: for me, it is not scrolled at all.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to problem of constraints. What happens if you set scrollview height to wrap content instead of 0dp.